# Trimming a Float up to a certain decimal point

Tags: c#

I need a way to round down a float up to a specific number of decimal places. `Math.Round` will round up if the number after the cut is larger than 6, and `Math.Floor` does not work with decimal places.

Basically if I have `2.566321`, I want the code to return `2.56`. The only way I know that this can be done is to convert the float to a string and use `string.format` but I would rather not do that if possible.

Thanks.

Comment: I cannot use the examples in that code as they assume you know how long the floating number is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A brute force way might be to multiply by 10^n where `n` is the number of decimal places you want, cast to int (which does truncation rather than rounding), then cast back to float and divide by 10^n again.

visually:

```
2.566321 * 10^2 = 2.566321 * 100 = 256.6321

(int) 256.6321 = 256

(float) 256 / 10^2 = (float) 256 / 100 = 2.56
```

Quick attempt at the code:

```
public float Truncate(float value, int decimalPlaces) {
   int temp = (int) (value * Math.Pow(10, decimalPlaces));
   return (float) temp / Math.Pow(10, decimalPlaces);
}
```

I haven't tested this, but that should get you going.

Comment: Thanks, I used a similar method.